# How to calculate the complex integral $ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(1-s^2)^4 e^{isc}}{(w-s)^{k}} ds $?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, complex-integration

> $$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{(1-s^2)^4 e^{isc}}{(w-s)^{k}} ds $$
>   for some constant $c$ and $w$, and for $k=1,2,3$.

I tried mathematica, but it gives me a quite complicated result. Just wonder whether it is possible to find a simpler expression.

Comment: WHAT result was obtained by Mathematica and WHAT are your own thoughts?

Comment: Does the $isc$ stand for inverse symbolic calculator? :-)

Comment: what is the range of $w$